# DDMS to get current location in android studio

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, ddms

In my project , I'm using google map and I want to center the map on the current location of the user . I couldn't use the gps diectlty but when I've done some researches , I found that I have to use DDMS to get the location given by gps , the problem is that it's giving me the wrong location , and I have to send it manually to the app so I really don't know how it's supposed to work in a smartphone directly . 
Thank you

Comment: What is DDMS? I know DMS, DEG, DM

Comment: Android Studio includes a debugging tool called the Dalvik Debug Monitor Server (DDMS)...

Answer (score 0):

There are indeed a lot of steps involved in getting the user's current location. On the other hand [DDMS](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html) is just a tool that is shipped with Android Studio or Eclipse that helps developers to know the app performance when it comes to Memory Management and Processes management.

Android's [Fused Location API](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi) is something you should start looking at that provides a precis location of a device on Google Maps. Android Manifest has various permissions that would enable an app to use the GPS using the ***fine location*** and ***coarse location*** of the device. Further the logic of the code would cover the *Google Play Services instantiation*, *Location Manager object*, *SupportMapFragment for map layout*.

Take a look at this [tutorial](http://javapapers.com/android/android-show-current-location-on-map-using-google-maps-api/) to get a step by step explanation.